# change in Items of listview Ui from Asynctask

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

Hi all android developers
I try to change each row of Listview in AsyncTask and show Download status of it as:

```
public OnlineStoreAdapter extends
    ArrayAdapter<MusicDownloadStructure>{ 
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final MusicDownloadStructure data = ModelDownloadData[position];
        data.setStatusTextView((TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tab2_downloadProgressText))T;
         .
         .
        Downloadbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            downloadmanager = new ModelDownload(URL, data);
           downloadmanager.execute(); 
        }
   }
}
```

I try to change row items of ListView by keeping reference of  **Textview** in data object and then change content of it in AsyncTask as:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (Isdownloaded) {
            DownloadStructure.setDownloadStatus(TitleStirng);
            TextView statusTextView = DownloadStructure.getStatusTextView();
            statusTextView.setText(TitleStirng);
            statusTextView.invalidate();
        } else {
            DownloadStructure.setDownloadStatus(TitleStirng);
            DownloadStructure.getStatusTextView().setText(TitleStirng);
        }
    }
```

**Problem** how can change in Listview UI from another thread (Asynctansk) and update it ?

Comment: What error do you get? Please post your complete getView code

Comment: @BlazeTama there isnt any error but my view dosnt change on download completion also setText() method as You see

Answer (score -1):

First of all, make us of the AsyncTask's OnProgressUpdate method, for example:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
{
    int current = values[0];
    int total = values[1];
    float percentage = 100 * (float) current / (float) total;

    update listview download progress here...
    tv.setText((int) percentage);//Just an example, you might to do a cast to a string...
}
```

And then in your doInBackground method of the AsyncTask, you update the progress as follows:

```
publishProgress(current,total);
```

This should update the progress. If the AsyncTask is run from a different context, you can use a Handler to send messages back to the listview's context/activity.

Comment: tanks but its not my quesiton my problem is my Ui dosent change even so i have declare setText() on onPost method

Comment: @FxRi4 , then you must use a handler. Define a handler on the ui thread and send update messages to the handler which will then from there update your listview.